# Jquery toggle between two images with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with five links.  Each link opens up a lightbox (using prettyphoto) with two images (the user can toggle between these) and a paragraph.

I have a simple Jquery script that toggles between the two images.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wmw9K/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.unactive').live('click', function(){
    $('a.button').toggleClass('unactive');
    $('div.show').toggle('blind','',500);
    console.log('clicked');
});

});​
```

This function works fine.  The problem results when the user toggles between the images in the lightbox and when they close the lightbox and open a new one, both images are displayed. **Please see an example of the problem here:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HU8zx/101/).**

**In sum, I cannot switch between lightboxes on a page and have this toggle function correctly.  I can only toggle between two images in a single lightbox without having to refresh the page.**

My question is how I can modify this Jquery function so it will work when the user opens and closes different lightboxes on a page?  Is there some reset I can use or should there be a modification to the HTML structure?  Or is there an alternative method of toggling images?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you uniquely identified each lightbox?

Comment: Yes, I give each div that holds the lightbox content its own unique id.

Comment: your image tags should end in: `"/>` not `"></img>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't agree with the inferences drawn so far. I think there is a bug in prettyphoto. When you show / hide, it creates a new container and copies the code to it. During copy, css display:none property of div is being lost.

In fact all the time, when you think you are working with 2 elements (two link or two divs) you are working with 4. 2 original and 2 cloned.

A simple workaround is to work only with cloned:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.button.unactive', "div.pp_content_container").live('click', function() {
        $('a.button', "div.pp_content_container").toggleClass('unactive');
        $('div.show', "div.pp_content_container").toggle('blind','',500);
        console.log('clicked');
    });
});​
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/HU8zx/114/

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is related to this inline style:  Try removing it.

```
   <div id="thediv" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: I think this might be a start.  However, now all the lightbox content is being displayed by default and it needs to be hidden and only displayed if the user clicks the link.

Comment: Try giving  `#thediv` a large margin: http://jsfiddle.net/HU8zx/113/
instead of `display:none`

Comment: That appears to solve the issue but now the page has a gigantic horizontal scroll.  Anyway that can be fixed?

Comment: I ended up doing position:absolute; left:-9999px; -- this seems to do the trick.  I just hope it doesn't cause errors later in my development.